# aspx client side dynamically create asp tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, client-side

I am trying to dynamically create asp code on the client side.
I have this kind of code:

```
 <% foreach (Product item in ProductList())
       {  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="center_prod_box">
```

I want to add information of each of my products. I have no problem of extracting the item's data into simple html tags as this:

```
<div class="product_title"><%:item.Name %></div>
      <div class="product_img"><img src="Images/<%:System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"+item.Image))?item.Image:"default_image.jpg"%>" alt="" width="60" height="60" border="0" /></div>
      <div class="prod_price"> <span class="price"><%:item.Price%></span></div>
```

As you see, <%:item.FIELD%> works in any html tag.

But what if I want the tags to be asp object and not plain HTML? This kind of thing does not work:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="addToCart" class="prod_buy" OnClick="Add_Click" CommandArgument="<%#item.Code%>"/>
```

I get an error: "The name 'item' does not exists in the current context".

How can I dynamically create asp object on an aspx client side?

Comment: In case of button you are using <%# that is basically databinding, but there is no Data Bound control, so you need to use <% or <%:

Comment: it just prints out the text as is , the arguments are <%item.code%> and same as with :

Comment: Try using `CommandArgument="<%# Eval("item.Code")%>"`

Comment: nope :( it same as before

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is a server-side technology. The client side cannot create server-side tags.

Comment: so what is the solution for this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Create client-side tags from the client, or server-side tags from the server.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net is a server technology that is parsed on the server and creates HTML and JavaScript dynamically which is then passed on to the client.  The client browser is technology agnostic; it does not know or care if the server used ASP.Net, Ruby/Rails, PHP, Java, or any other technology to create the HTML and JavaScript.  If you are trying to change the output on the client, you must either use JavaScript to make calls to the server to request the new information and then change the data values (Commonly referred to as AJAX, an acronym for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML), or you must do a full Postback to the server and have the server re-render the HTML.  Newer ASP technologies (ASP.Net MVC, for example) use a combination of Server Side and JavaScript technologies to make this process less manual, but they are ultimately hiding the implementation of AJAX calls.

**Edit**

After re-reading your post, I believe I understand what you are trying to do.  The CommandArgument is a literal string which you are trying to write the value of a variable into before passing it to the client.  In order to do this, you need to use the #Eval keyword, i.e. `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("item.Code")%>'`.  This establishes a one way binding for this value in the string property.

Comment: I know this. But it doesnt help. The client will recieve an html, no matter if I will write <%:item.Name %> or <asp:button runat="server" OnClick="Add_Click" CommandArgument="blabla"> . Both case translte to HTML on the browser. So why can't it be a combintaion?

Comment: Yep, It seems to me that by 'Client Side' He actually means the Markup. Where Client Side is usually used to refer to DHTML functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no way to reference an asp variable inside a given server control.

I would suggest using a Repeater instead, as it generates no HTML, gives you access to the active item and makes it possible to eval values on server controls.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Name") %>
        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Code") %>'/>      
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Binding it:

```
rpt.DataSource = ProductList();
rpt.DataBind();
```

One disadvantage would be the lack of flux control (if statement). In case you need that, you could use PlaceHolders:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phTrue" runat="server" Visible='<%# Condition %>' >
            <div>True</div>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phFlase" runat="server" Visible='<%# !Condition %>' >
            <div>False</div>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```